# Detecting voice call disconnection with Twilio iOS client SDK

Tags: ios, twilio, voip

I am using Twilio iOS SDK. The problem i am facing is that when i make an outgoing call and the called party disconnects, I am not receiving any delegate callbacks. I have implemented the TCConnectionDelegate method `connectionDidDisconnect`. It is never invoked in this case. On the other hand i can successfully disconnect calls from the calling device.

I have tested using their sample app "Basic Phone" . The same problem exists in that app too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Twilio support itself on this and searching for other solutions,   I have reached the conclusion that Twilio iOS SDK does not provide the required functionality. Alternate methods such as using APNS or Pusher will have to be used so as to notify the client about call state changes