# detecting user disconnection from twilio room due to internet problems

Tags: swift, xcode, twilio, twilio-api

I am using the twilio api, and there are are users connected to a room streaming their videos to it. However when one of the users disconnects, due to internet disconnection problems, the delegate which registers his disconnection from the room, does not get called.
I wanted to ask how do I detect when a user disconnects due to internet problems? is making a periodic pings to all the users, the only way to do it? if yes, is there any way I can access the participant IPs to ping via the TVIParticipant?

Comment: Try seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052906/detecting-voice-call-disconnection-with-twilio-ios-client-sdk

Comment: That previous question refers to Twilio Client, not Twilio Video. Are you saying that when a user disconnects with a connection error you are not receiving the `participantDidDisconnect` callback on your object that implements `TVIRoomDelegate`?

Comment: @philnash yes, exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then. I will ask internally and see what I can find out.

Comment: Would you be able to send me (philnash@twilio.com) a room SID for a chat where this happened? I can send it on to our team to take a look and explain what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is actually a known error. The Twilio infrastructure can take up to 120 seconds to dispatch the disconnect event in this situation.

Please keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/issues/99) for proposed improvements, progress and ETA on the issue.

Comment: is there any logic we can implement to handle this? as twilio doesn't have an answer for this yet